# How to make the section title uppercase, leaving the footnote text of a section title to be not uppercase in LaTeX?

Tags: footnotes, titlesec

I want the section title to be automatically made uppercase. So I used the `\titleformat` command together with the `titlesec` package. The collateral effect is that a footnote of the section title appears in uppercase as well. Indeed, the `\protect\footnote` works well with all the text formatting (e.g `\slshape`) but uppercase!

How should I do? Here a MWE:

```latex
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}{\slshape\MakeUppercase}{\thesection.}{0.5em}{}
\usepackage{babel}

\begin{document}
\section{I want section title to be uppercase\protect\footnote{But I want the footnote text of a section title to be not uppercase}}
This is the section text
\end{document}
```

In the example above:

- the section title is *italic* and UPPERCASE (both are correct)
- the footnote is NOT *italic* (which is correct), but still UPPERCASE (I do not want this!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}{\slshape\MakeUppercase}{\thesection.}{0.5em}{}
\usepackage{babel}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section[I want section title to be uppercase]{I want section title to be uppercase\protect\footnotemark}
\footnotetext{But I want the footnote text of a section title to be not uppercase}
This is the section text
\end{document}
```